# Parse xml/wsdl string with PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, soap, wsdl

I consumed using php-curl, a webservice API with soap-wsdl which doesn't return an xml object but a string like:

```
string(3854) "<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/ 01/oasis- 200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><s:Header><o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ wss/2004/ 01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><u:Timestamp u:Id="_0"><u:Created>2022-03-18T01:53:32.688Z</ u:Created> <u:Expires>2022-03-18T01:58:32.688Z</u:Expires></u:Timestamp></o:Security></s:Header><s:Body><UrbanList xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><D"...
```

How to turn the content of this string into an xml and parse this to an array, object, json... anything but a string?

Comment: You should use `SoapClient` to parse the `wsdl`. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8989609/1529324

Comment: @AndreaOlivato but this is the only way ? i need only to convert the string to a true xml or any accessible object.

Comment: You can use a [simplexml_load_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) to just get an XML object but that's not the purpose of a wsdl

Comment: @AndreaOlivato simplexml dont work with string generated with complex xml like generated by wdsl. Always return null for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$your_soap_string = 'YOUR SOAP STRING HERE';
$namespaces = ['s:', 'o:', 'u:']; // you need to add all if there are more
$clean_xml = str_ireplace($namespaces, '', $your_soap_string);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($clean_xml);
```